# how can to convert array from jsp to javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jsp, markers

please i work in project and i want to display many markers on map , i  want to display arr[][] from jsp to javascrpit like this code,
please i work in project and i want to display many markers on map , i  want to display arr[][] from jsp to javascrpit like this code
for ex: 
    i want to replace this code :

```
 for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: new google.maps.LatLng( 17.088291,78.442383 ),
             map: map,
         });
```

to :

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: new google.maps.LatLng( arr[i][0],arr[i][1] ),
             map: map,
          });
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<script     src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD4DvaNOnpTRUFASvy6lyY0DDVcfXytvnY&libraries=places&&callback=initMap">
</script>
<script>
<%!
double arr[][]= new double[3][2];
%>
    <%
 arr[0][0]=19.088291;
 arr[0][1]= 78.442383;
arr[1][0]=18.088291;
arr[1][1]=78.442383;
arr[2][0]=17.088291;
arr[2][1]=78.442383;


    %>
function loadMap() {
var mapOptions = {
center:new google.maps.LatLng(19.373341, 78.662109),
zoom:7
}

var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("sample"),mapOptions);

//animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
 for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng( 17.088291,78.442383 ),
map: map,
});

        }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="loadMap()">
<div id="sample" style="width:580px;height:400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this code display one marker

Comment: yes i know but when i replace the nested loop to 
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(arr[i][0], arr[i][1]),
map: map,
});
        }
not work ...

Comment: i think that ... arr defined at jsp code but javascript code can't read it

Comment: thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simple answer 
add this line in jsp code 
 String json = new Gson().toJson(array);

and in javascript add this line 
 var arr=<%=json%>; 
code will work

Answer (score 0):

I think you have got two options here:

A. Use `out.print` in the loop, it I think you already tried that but forgot something very important - `<%` and `%>`

So the final line of code should look like:

```
new google.maps.LatLng(<% out.print(arr[i][0]); %>, <% out.print(arr[i][1]); %>
```

B. Convert the whole JSP array to JSON and decode back. Although not the simplest solution but can be useful in many places like external services etc. You can use a library like Gson.

Comment: first options not work because in this part <% out.print(arr[i][0]); %> javascript can't define i 

second options work done

Comment: Just use a JSP loop and embed the JavaScript part within the JSP loop block.